# Recursivly traverse simple tree in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a simple tree which takes the shape below

```
    ROOT
     /\
    A  B
   /    \ 
  A1     B1
          \
           B11
```

This is stored in a DB table CLASSES that is self referencing.

```
 ID |  CLASS_ID  | PARENT_ID
 ---------------------------
  1 |     ROOT   |  
  2 |     A      | ROOT
  3 |     A1     | A
  4 |     B      | ROOT
  5 |     B1     | B
  6 |     B11    | B1
 ---------------------------
```

and so on, this is just an example, the class_id and parent_id columns are integers but I just made them chars for this example so you get the idea.

I then have a second table CHILDREN which I want to look like this in the end,

```
 ID | CLASS_ID   | CHILD_CLASS_ID
 --------------------------------
  1 |     ROOT   |  A
  2 |     ROOT   |  A1
  3 |     ROOT   |  B
  4 |     ROOT   |  B1
  5 |     ROOT   |  B11
  6 |     A      |  A1
  7 |     B      |  B1
  8 |     B      |  B11
  9 |     B1     |  B11
 ---------------------------
```

So essentially if a class is lower than any class within its branch it is a child of all higher classes. I know this is definitely a recursion problem but I am new to PHP could really use some help. I am running mysql. I should also mention that I will be traversing backwards. So I am inserting classes at the bottom. An example would be the next class to insert would be A11, I would then need to traverse up to find all higher classes and make them parent classes of A11.

Comment: The question is how iterate a multidimensional resultset or how to get the resultset in the first place?

Comment: Well I would like to be able to get the result set but if I can iterate it to the point where I get to each parent id then I can do an insert on the child table. So either would work for me.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. *tsk*

Comment: @Sherri, Indeed it does look like a homework problem but I assure it it is not. I gave a generic example example of my problem using letters and numbers so my project specific stuff would not confuse anyone as to what my actual question was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I have grasped what you are trying to do. Do you have to work backwards to create the child table?

If you work from the top down you can gather all child IDs for each parent using a MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT PARENT_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CLASS_ID) AS CHILDREN
FROM CLASSES
GROUP BY PARENT_ID
```

This should return something like:

```
| PARENT_ID | CHILDREN      |
-----------------------------
| ROOT      | A,A1,B,B1,B11 |
| A         | A1            |
| B         | B1,B11        |
| A1        |               |
| B1        | B11           |
| B11       |               |
-----------------------------
```

Then you can break that up and populate your CHILDREN table?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it the was you have? Its a REALLLLY bad way in my opinion. You're queries become complex, where as if you use a **Adjacency List**, it is simple.

Take a look at this.

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I mistyped Nested Set in place of Ajacency List, so I have edited it out.

Comment: His first table is an adjacency list (ie. the one with the recursive relation). He should look at nested sets (or combine both). When using a PHP ORM solution like Propel or Doctrine, working with nested sets is very easy. But the link you provided above is indeed a must read, it will clarify a lot of things.